# OSX Open Directory Network Users Problem and Kerberos

Tags: macos, server.app, dns, network-user, open-directory

I've got a Mavericks Server mostly working, but I still get some funkiness.  Main problem is that I've been having a great deal of trouble getting network user accounts with home directories on the server to function.

So, I've gone to http://yesdevnull.net/ and have been going through testing from the beginning.

I want your input on this DNS issue.  My router is providing DNS for the server.  When I did the initial setup, I ran this on the server

```
sudo changeip -checkhostname
```

and got this:

```
Primary address     = 192.168.12.3
Current HostName    = server.mydomain.net
DNS HostName        = server.mydomain.net
```

The names match. There is nothing to change.

```
dirserv:success = "success"
```

So, I figured DNS is working correctly.

But, since I still have issues, I decided to dig deeper and ran this on a client:

```
dig -x 192.168.12.3
```

and got this:

```
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9219
;; flags: qr; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;3.12.168.192.in-addr.arpa.    IN    PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
3.12.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 3600    IN    PTR    server.mydomain.net.

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.12.1#53(192.168.12.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Jan 26 07:47:23 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 75
```

Compared to Mr. Barrett's example at http://yesdevnull.net/, the differences are that my flags for AUTHORITY and ADDITIONAL are 0, while his are 1 and of course there is no AUTHORITY SECTION: or ADDITIONAL SECTION:

Do people see that as a cause for problems?

If so, I can certainly setup DNS on the server and change all the clients to use the server's IP for their DNS server.

Steps for that?  This would be my plan:

On server:

- Setup DNS
- Retest Lookups as above

Will I need to destroy Open Directory and start over?  If so, it might be faster for me to re-setup Mav Server, BUT i'd really like to do it without reinstalling since I have the server setup with some other services (its providing print services for ipads using something called Handyprint, its running a python based server to receive phots from eye-fi cards in my cameras, and a few other things that I'd like to avoid having to setup again).

On clients:

- unbind clients
- Change clients DNS Clean out old OD certificates from client keychains
- Ensure that previous computer records are not in OD and remove using WGM if necessary
- Rebind Clients

Comment: I realize this is a bit old and didn't generate answers. I can answer part and hope that others can jump in as I have issues that I believe are Kerberos related. My experience is that any time you make changes to the DNS configuration of the server providing OD, you'll have to rebuild OD. This is the case because the keys/certs generated may not match and will likely cause problems with binding, etc.

Comment: @iLikeStrongJava: What exactly do you mean by "rebuild OD?"